# How do i resize an image based on its div width?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I'm in the beginning stages of my 1st bootstrap site, and can't remember how to pass the `document.getElementByClass("mydiv").offsetWidth` to the CSS in order to dynamically scale the SVG images contained in it.

The HTML:

```
  <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 >Title</h2>
            </div> <!-- end panel-heading -->
            <a href="link.html"><img src="images/image.svg" alt="Title"></a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div> <!-- end panel -->
    </div> <!-- end .col-3 .col-sm-3 .col-lg-->
```

The CSS:

```
.panel  img {
    width:  ???
}
```

Apologies for any posting protocol issues. Stackoverflow n00b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a grid system, why don't you display the image as `block` and use `width: 100%` to fill the entire space of the column?

```css
.panel  img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I am seriously facepalming here. That was so simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var panelWidth = $(this).closest('.panel').width();
    $(this).width(panelWidth);
});
```

Actually, you can give your images a class to make the selector more specific.

Comment: buddy I think `?` is in css code

Answer (score 0):

Also i suggest you to include `max-width:100%;` so that it won't go behind your div any time if you make any changes to `width`.